# Is it possible to do vote and participate in crowd-sale using Forwarder address?

Tags: solidity, tokens, crowdsale, voting

Currently, I am using Metamask (Ropsten TestNet).
And I want to implement one voting cum crowd-sale process, the scenario is given below:

1. Want to make the voting process in this if Voter is voted to one choice it has to transfer one token from own address to voting destination address which is predefined.
2. Right now I am assigning few tokens to that voter(forwarder / external address). But the problem is, to vote successfully I have to make that voter my msg.sender which is not applicable for metamask, because forwarder is created by Multisig wallet, not by metamask.